# Is it possible to create a WAR file using the Java JRE?

Tags: java, jdk, jre

Using the Java JDK you can use the jar command to create a war file:

`jar -cvf /tmp/mywar.war *`

There is a way to work with `.jar` files with the Java JRE but can you create jar or war files with it?

`/path_to_java/java -jar ???`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can you create jar or war files with the JRE?

No. The JRE does not ship with `jar.exe`.

In order to create jar or war files you need to install the JDK.